# JPA 2.0 OneToOne Mapping Reference an Attribute

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

Is it possible to reference a single attribute in the referenced entity, in a OneToOne relationship

Example :

```
   @Entity
   public class Country {
    @Id
    private Long countryId;
   @Column(name="code")
   private String countryCode;
  ...
  } 

 @Entity
 public class City {

  @Id
  private Long cityId;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="countryId",referencedColumnName="cityId")
    @Column(name="code")
    private String countryCode;
```

}

With this setup I get the error @Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne property. Is it possible to do this in any other way in JPA 2.0

Thx
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can simply add an accessor for such use cases which delegates to the referenced entity:

```
public class City {
  public String getCountryCode() { 
    return null == country ? null : country.getCountryCode(); 
  }
}
```